# How to prove this LP problem?

Tags: linear-programming

Prove that any LP optimization problem can be transformed into the following form:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} && 0 · x \\
 \text{subject to} && Ax &= b\\
     && x&\ge 0
\end{align*}

If the LP is feasible, then it has an optimum value of 0

If the LP is not feasible, then it has an optimal value of infinity

0 is zero. I think the above function is not a dual function. How to prove it?

Comment: How do you define LP-problem (so what form is *your* standard form)? And I doubt that that is true as written (because the function to minimize is a constant ...

Comment: The standard form can be written as: maximize c^Tx with constraints Ax=b and x>=0. If we minimize or maximize a constant it's always true right? Because we have already had the optimal value which is that constant.